# Save Word Files with Filenames as Increasing Numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found a macro on the internet which saves the selection from a Word document as a new document.

```vb
Sub SaveSelectedTextToNewDocument()
    If Selection.Words.Count > 0 Then
        'Copy the selected text
        Selection.Copy

        'Open a new document and paste the copied text into it
        Dim objNewDoc As Document
        Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add
        Selection.Paste

        'Get the first 10 characters as the filename of the new document and save them
        Dim objFileName As Range
        Set objFileName = objNewDoc.Range(Start:=0, End:=10)
        objNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\" & objFileName & ".docx"
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

I don't want to save the files with filename as the first 10 letters of the document. I want the filenames to be in increasing numbers instead (e.g. 1.docx, 2.docx, 3.docx and so on).

Comment: So you're wanting Word to remember the last number between occasions when you use the macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a macro that should work:

```
Sub SaveSelectedTextToNewDocumentNumbered()
' Charles Kenyon  16 October 2021
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593130/save-word-files-with-filenames-as-increasing-numbers-using-macro
'
Retry:
    If Selection.Words.Count > 0 Then
        'Copy the selected text
        Selection.Copy

        'Open a new document and paste the copied text into it
        Dim objNewDoc As Document
        Dim currentDoc As Document
        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Set currentDoc = ActiveDocument
        On Error GoTo CreateVar
        i = currentDoc.Variables("SaveNum")
        On Error GoTo -1
        i = i + 1
        Let sFileName = currentDoc.Name
        Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add
        Selection.Paste
        ' save  and assign name
        objNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=sFileName & i
        ' update variable
        currentDoc.Variables("SaveNum") = i
        ' save original document with new variable
        currentDoc.Save
        ' cleanup
        Set currentDoc = Nothing
        Set objNewDoc = Nothing
        On Error GoTo -1
    End If
    Exit Sub
CreateVar:
    ActiveDocument.Variables("SaveNum") = 0
    GoTo Retry
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it really helped me a lot but I had to do some changes to get the exact results I asked for, since I wanted the file names to be like 1.docx, 2.docx and so on. I just changed these two lines and I got what exactly I wanted 1) `Let sFileName = ""` 2) `objNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=sFileName & i & ".docx"`